# Setting dijit.Tree cookie for all pages

Tags: tree, dojo

I'm using the same dijit.Tree view over several pages in our application, and I'd like to have the cookie saved for the server name, instead of the folder name.
Right now I've got 3 pages and 3 cookies, which each hold their own information on the state of the Tree, which is kinda annoying.

Any ways to accomplish this? The only thing I've found on cookies in the [API](http://api.dojotoolkit.org/jsdoc/1.3.2/dijit.Tree), is that I can set the `cookieName` and turn cookies on/off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems that `Tree.js` won't let you set attributes for the cookie. So I just had to overwrite the `_saveState()` method for the `Tree`:

```
var treeControl = new dijit.Tree({
    model: treeModel,
    showRoot: false,
    openOnClick: false,
    cookieName: "OrganizationUnitTreeState",
    _saveState: function(){
        // summary:
        // Create and save a cookie with the currently expanded nodes identifiers
        // Overre the default saveState function, so we can set the cookie path
        if(!this.persist){
            return;
        }
        var ary = [];
        for(var id in this._openedItemIds){
            ary.push(id);
        }
        dojo.cookie(this.cookieName, ary.join(","), {expires:365, path:"/"});
    },
    /* Many more methods */
});
```

It's the last line of code there that does the trick. The `dojo.cookie()` takes a list of key/value pairs, which will be transformed into cookie attributes, so if you want any other attributes set, this is how you'd do it.

Comment: Very useful. 'Twould be nice if the was an official API for changing tree persistance to site-wide. You may file an enhancement ticket.